# GeoPandas link columns and iterate through multipolygon

Tags: python, geopandas

I have shapefile, which has two columns. One is Zone, and second is geometry (which contains multipolygon). What I need is just simply iterate through Zone and then iterate through her multipolygon.

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
print(shapefile)
```

this will output:

```
                           ZONA                                           geometry
0    Zóna A  MULTIPOLYGON (((-516009.680 -1330712.290, -515...
1   Zóna B  MULTIPOLYGON (((-492312.000 -1332520.800, -492...
2  Zóna C  MULTIPOLYGON (((-475239.270 -1332875.000, -475...
3   Zóna D  MULTIPOLYGON (((-534920.800 -1315175.400, -535...
```

Simply I just cant figure it out, how to reach this pseudo code:

```
for multipolygon in zones:
    for polygon in multipolygon:
          be_happy(polygon)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file("file.shp")
shapefile = shapefile.to_crs(epsg=4326)
done = dict()
for tuples in shapefile.itertuples():
    done[tuples[1]] = []
    for polygon in tuples[2].geoms:
        done[tuples[1]].append(polygon)
```

Updated for shapely 2.0

Comment: The `return` statement MUST be inside a function in Python.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/241622)

Comment: This is complete answer. Look at pseudocode once again and maybe then you will see the similiarities

Answer (score 1):

You can use geopandas explode method. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
shapefile_exploded = shapefile.explode()
```

Comment: tried - not working as expected. itertuples() did the trick